# Async function: for-Loop object empty after await statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

**tldr at the bottom:**

I don't really know how to explain my problem so I start with an example.
I have this async function (in reactJS but I think this is a JS related issue).

```
 onUploadDrop = async (e, folderId) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // check if the user uploaded files or folders
        var uploadedItems = e.dataTransfer.items;
        let files = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < uploadedItems.length; i++) {
            let item = uploadedItems[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
            if (item.isDirectory) {
                alert("is directory")
            } else {
                var file = await this.getFileByWebkitEntry(item);
                files.push(file);
            }
            console.log(i);
        }

     // do something with files[]
    }
```

This function is calling another async function:

```
getFileByWebkitEntry = async (item) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        item.file(function (file) {
            resolve(file);
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            resolve("");
        });
    });
}
```

I'm looping through e.datatransfer.files which are basically some uploaded files or folders. Unfortunately this for-loop gets only executed once.

I did some debugging and found out that if I place a `console.log` before and after this line: `var file = await ...` This comes out:

[image]

**tldr: After the await statement uploadedItems is empty thus ending the loop. Why is this happening?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by not using async - await but Promises instead.
It looks like this:

```
onUploadDrop = (e, folderId) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // check if the user uploaded files or folders
        var uploadedItems = e.dataTransfer.items;
        let promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < uploadedItems.length; i++) {
            let item = uploadedItems[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
            if (item.isDirectory) {
                alert("is directory")
            } else {
                promises.push(this.getFileByWebkitEntry(item));
            }
            console.log(i);
        }

        Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
            // do something with result (result = files)
        });
```

Comment: Just to complete this answer: you could still use async-await when using promises like this. But instead of awaiting when you push the promise. You wait when you try to resolve all promises: at promise.all. -- `await Promise.all(promises);`. This has the benefit of the function only returning after the promises have finisehd (or one failed); thus no dangling code occurs.